# Issue with Agent Collecting 10 Products and Returning to Starting Point in a 12x11 Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have a 12x11 matrix. I want my agent to start from row 0, column 5 (reward points 1) and collect 10 products (reward points 100) and return to the starting point again. The problem is that once the agency starts its action it only collects 1 reward and stays there. I want it to collect the remaining 10 products and take them to row 0, in short, 5. What is my mistake?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

environment_rows = 12
environment_columns = 11

# Hyperparameters
alpha = 0.1  # learning rate
gamma = 0.8  # discount factor
epsilon = 0.99  # exploration rate
num_episodes = 1000  # number of episodes for training

actions = ['up', 'right', 'down', 'left']
q_values = np.zeros((environment_rows, environment_columns, 4))

rewards = np.full((environment_rows, environment_columns), -5.)
rewards[0, 5] = 1

depo = {}
depo[2] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[3] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[4] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[5] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[6] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[7] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[8] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[9] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
depo[10] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

for row_index in range(2, 11):
    for column_index in depo[row_index]:
        rewards[row_index, column_index] = -100.
                
def define_order_states(file_path):
    order_list = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/kullanıcı/Desktop/siparis_listesi.csv")

    # Sipariş durumlarının ödülünü belirle
    order_rewards = 100

    # Sipariş listesindeki her satır için
    for index, row in order_list.iterrows():
        # Ürünün satır ve sütun numaralarını al
        product_row = row['Satır']
        product_column = row['Sütun']

        # Ödüller tablosunda ilgili hücrenin ödülünü sipariş ödülü olarak güncelle
        rewards[product_row, product_column] = order_rewards

# Dosya yolu parametresiyle fonksiyonu çağır
define_order_states("C:/Users/kullanıcı/Desktop/siparis_listesi.csv")

def get_starting_location():
  current_row_index = 0
  current_column_index = 5
  return current_row_index, current_column_index 

def get_next_action(current_row_index, current_column_index, epsilon):
    if np.random.random() < epsilon:
        return np.random.randint(4)
    else:
        return np.argmax(q_values[current_row_index, current_column_index])

def get_next_location(current_row_index, current_column_index, action_index):
    new_row_index = current_row_index
    new_column_index = current_column_index

    if actions[action_index] == 'up' and current_row_index > 0:
        new_row_index -= 1
    elif actions[action_index] == 'right' and current_column_index < environment_columns - 1:
        new_column_index += 1
    elif actions[action_index] == 'down' and current_row_index < environment_rows - 1:
        new_row_index += 1
    elif actions[action_index] == 'left' and current_column_index > 0:
        new_column_index -= 1

    return new_row_index, new_column_index

# Learning loop
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    # Get starting location for the episode
    current_state = get_starting_location()
    is_terminal = False

    while not is_terminal:
        # Choose action using epsilon-greedy strategy
        action = get_next_action(current_state[0], current_state[1], epsilon)

        # Get next location based on the chosen action
        next_state = get_next_location(current_state[0], current_state[1], action)

        # Get immediate reward for the next state
        immediate_reward = rewards[next_state[0], next_state[1]]

        # Update Q-value for the current state and action using Bellman equation
        q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1], action] += alpha * (
                immediate_reward + gamma * np.max(q_values[next_state[0], next_state[1]]) -
                q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1], action])

        # Move to the next state
        current_state = next_state

        # Check if the agent reached the terminal state
        if rewards[current_state[0], current_state[1]] == 100 or rewards[current_state[0], current_state[1]] == -100:
            
            is_terminal = True 
        
def reset_order_rewards():
    global rewards
    rewards = np.full((environment_rows, environment_columns), -1.)
    rewards[0, 5] = 100.
    for row_index in range(2, 11):
        for column_index in depo[row_index]:
            rewards[row_index, column_index] = -100.
    # Başlangıç noktasına dönme ödülünü ayarlayalım
    rewards[0, 5] = 50.  # Örneğin, 50 puan 

# Optimal politikayı takip etmek ve başlangıç noktasına geri dönmek için
def follow_optimal_policy():
    current_state = get_starting_location()
    total_reward = 0
    route = [current_state]

    while True:
        action = np.argmax(q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1]])
        next_state = get_next_location(current_state[0], current_state[1], action)
        immediate_reward = rewards[next_state[0], next_state[1]]
        total_reward += immediate_reward
        current_state = next_state
        route.append(current_state)

        print(f"Seçilen aksiyon: {actions[action]}, Yeni durum: {current_state}")

        if immediate_reward == 100 or immediate_reward == -100 or current_state == get_starting_location():
            break

    return total_reward, route

# Eğitim döngüsü
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    # Epsilon değerini her bölümde %10 azaltın
    epsilon = epsilon * 0.9

    current_state = get_starting_location()
    is_terminal = False

    while not is_terminal:
        action = get_next_action(current_state[0], current_state[1], epsilon)
        next_state = get_next_location(current_state[0], current_state[1], action)
        immediate_reward = rewards[next_state[0], next_state[1]]

        q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1], action] += alpha * (
                immediate_reward + gamma * np.max(q_values[next_state[0], next_state[1]]) -
                q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1], action])

        current_state = next_state

        if rewards[current_state[0], current_state[1]] == 100 or rewards[current_state[0], current_state[1]] == -100:
            is_terminal = True

            # Terminal durum için Q-tablosunu güncelleyin (gerekiyorsa)
            if rewards[current_state[0], current_state[1]] == 100:
                q_values[current_state[0], current_state[1]] = 100  # Veya terminal durum için uygun bir değer
                
# Optimal politikayı takip etmek ve başlangıç noktasına geri dönmek için
total_reward, route = follow_optimal_policy()
print(f"Toplam ödül: {total_reward}")
print(f"Optimal rota: {route}")
```